# How to redirect tail of multiple files to a new file with newlines?

Tags: bash, cygwin, io-redirection, tail

I suspect this is an easy one. I have a directory of files and I need the last line from each file grouped into a new file.

I used:

```
tail -q myFile_seed*.csv > output.csv
```

But the output file is one long line. Is there a simple way to redirect with newlines so that each file is on its own line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your files do not have the usual `\r\n` appended to the final line of the file. In this case, you'll need to handle each file separately, rather than have `tail` process them all at once.

```
for f in myfile_seed*.csv; do
    tail -n 1 "$f"
    printf "\n"
done > output.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
tail -q -n 1 myFile_seed*.csv > output.csv
```

Comment: Same result. All the input lines are one big output line.

Comment: Most likely you have `\r` in your csv files, you can check it by using `tail -q -n 1 myFile_seed*.csv | cat -vte` command.

Comment: Or rather, none of the files have a newline on the final line.

Comment: They do not have newlines at the end, this is why I need to add one. Also there is no \r.

Answer (score 0):

Other option would be in one line;

```
    ls myFile_seed*.csv | xargs -ifile sh -c "tail -n 1 file; echo " > output.csv
```